# Bash Script User Input

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I need to write a script that asks for an absolute path directory, having trouble filling in the blanks any references or hints would help.

This is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Ask for absolute directory path

echo Please enter absolute directory path
read
```

(Now I don't quite know how to enter the variable for the absolute directory path, probably something basic I am over thinking).

Comment: `echo "$REPLY"`. Take a look at `help read`.

Comment: http://goo.gl/L4r7SE

Answer (score 1):

to store into variable $out user input:

```
read -p "Please enter absolute directory path?" out
echo "$out"
```